# How can i draw a 28*28 pixels digit in python using my mouse and then extract the pixel information and store it into a row vector or 28*28 matrix?

Tags: python

How can I draw a 28*28 pixels digit in python using my mouse and then extract the pixel information and store it into a row vector or 28*28 matrix? And recognize that drawn digit using machine learning decision tree algorithm. I am using kaggle data set to identify the digits. I am trying to use machine learning for digit recognition.

Comment: Why do you need to draw it first? There are lots of digit datasets that you could convert to 28x28 (if needed).